# Calculate SUM in T-SQL statement which uses CASE to output values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table containing orders which have been purchased on an e-commerce website and a second table detailing the products (essentially line items) for each order. My remit is to calculate the total cost and total weight of each product ordered, grouped by product.  The shop owner wants to be able to identify the product which sold the most by weight or by value.

The structure of the two tables is like this:

**Order**

```
id
orderDate
```

**OrderLine**

```
id
orderId
productNodeId
productName
quantity
duration
frequency
subscription
unitPrice
unitWeight
```

Whilst some of the order lines are simple one-off products (and are hence simple to calculate totals i.e. the total weight would be `quantity * unitWeight` and the total cost would be `quantity * unitCost`) other order lines are subscriptions, where the total weight would be calculated by `(duration/frequency) * unitWeight` and the total cost would be `(duration/frequency) * unitCost`.

I have the following T-SQL statement which uses CASE to return the total values *(running in SQL Server 2008R2 Express):*

```
SELECT 
  productNodeId AS id, 
  productName AS name, 
  quantity, 
  duration, 
  frequency, 
  subscription, 
  unitPrice,
  CASE   
    WHEN subscription = 1 THEN unitWeight*(duration/frequency)
  ELSE
    unitWeight*quantity
  END AS weight,
  CASE   
    WHEN subscription = 1 THEN unitPrice*(duration/frequency)
  ELSE
    unitPrice*quantity
  END AS total

FROM Order INNER JOIN OrderLine ON Order.id = OrderLine.orderId WHERE orderStatusId = 3

--GROUP BY productNodeId
ORDER BY total DESC
```

This works to an extent.  It outputs the following values:

```
id   |  name     | quantity | duration | frequency  | subscription | unitPrice | weight | total
1105    Option C   1          24          1            1              2.50        18000    60.00
1105    Option C   1          24          2            1              2.50        9000     30.00
1104    Option B   1          24          2            1              2.50        9000     30.00
1105    Option C   1          24          2            1              2.50        10800    30.00
1105    Option C   1          4          1             1              2.50        2000     10.00
1107    Option A   1          0          0             0              2.80        600      2.80
1107    Option A   1          0          0             0              2.80        600      2.80
1121    Option D   1          0          0             0              2.80        400      2.80
```

The final part though is to sum the totals.  However, I can't just implement the `GROUP BY productNodeId` statement commented out in the above code, as it requires the `subscription` field to be aggregated, which negates the conditional `weight` and `total` logic.

I wondered if anyone could suggest how to get this working so that I can return correct totals for weight and price?

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why don't you just put your case statements inside the SUM() function?;

Comment: Wonderful, that works great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment from @Anthony Hancock, the simplest solution was to wrap the `CASE` conditionals inside `SUM` aggregators, as follows:

```
SELECT 
  productNodeId AS id, 
  MAX(productName) AS name, 
  SUM(CASE   
    WHEN subscription = 1 THEN unitWeight*(duration/frequency)
  ELSE
    unitWeight*quantity
  END) AS weight,
  SUM(CASE   
    WHEN subscription = 1 THEN unitPrice*(duration/frequency)
  ELSE
    unitPrice*quantity
  END) AS total

FROM Order INNER JOIN OrderLine ON Order.id = OrderLine.orderId WHERE orderStatusId = 3
GROUP BY productNodeId
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to test this but you should be able to sub query the original query and apply your group by logic to the total fields keeping your conditionals intact.

```
select id,name,quantity,duration,frequency,subscription,unitprice,weight,sum(total) as sumedtotal

 from (
SELECT 
  productNodeId AS id, 
  productName AS name, 
  quantity, 
  duration, 
  frequency, 
  subscription, 
  unitPrice,
  CASE   
    WHEN subscription = 1 THEN unitWeight*(duration/frequency)
  ELSE
    unitWeight*quantity
  END AS weight,
  CASE   
    WHEN subscription = 1 THEN unitPrice*(duration/frequency)
  ELSE
    unitPrice*quantity
  END AS total

FROM Order INNER JOIN OrderLine ON Order.id = OrderLine.orderId WHERE orderStatusId = 3

--GROUP BY productNodeId
) as x
group by id,name,quantity,duration,frequency,subscription,unitprice,weight
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. It may well work but I tried the suggestion by Anthony in the comment on the original question which works nicely and appears a little simpler. Thanks though — appreciate the answer.